# How command /usr/sbin/rfkill called when /usr/sbin is not in $PATH?

Tags: bash, path

The PATH environment variable:

```
debian@debian:~$ echo  $PATH
/home/debian/.local/bin:/home/debian/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

We can see that `/usr/sbin` is not in the $PATH.
Execute a command:

```
sudo strace bash -c 'sudo rfkill unblock wlan'  2>&1 | grep  rfkill
```

The calls are traced as below:

```
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "sudo rfkill unblock wlan"], 0x7ffc8af3afd0 /* 17 vars */) = 0
execve("/usr/bin/sudo", ["sudo", "rfkill", "unblock", "wlan"], 0x55ba46abfa50 /* 20 vars */) = 0
stat("/usr/local/sbin/rfkill", 0x55f5cf165f80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/rfkill", 0x55f5cf165f80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/rfkill", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=47184, ...}) = 0
```

`rfkill` is called in the `/usr/sbin/rfkill`. Why is command /usr/sbin/rfkill called when /usr/sbin is not in $PATH?

Comment: I guess you mean `PATH`, not `path`.

Comment: yes ,it is PATH

Answer (score 1):

The secret is `sudo`,sudo matters.

```
cat  /etc/sudoers | rg path
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Comment: And indeed, the OP's `strace` shows that `/usr/sbin` **is** in the `PATH` that is used in the `sudo` context.  By default, `sudo` does not inherit environment from the process that launches it (technically, it clears the inherited environment before setting up its own).  This excerpt from `sudoers` demonstrates some defaults for how the sudo environment is configured, and it happens to exactly match the path search that the OP's `strace` reveals.

Answer (score 0):

You can always provide the path explicitly, i.e.assuming that `rfkill` resides in `/usr/sbin`, do a

```
sudo strace bash -c 'sudo /usr/sbin/rfkill unblock wlan'  2>&1 | grep  rfkill
```

In your case, it seems to be in the PATH, but you don't query the PATH correctly, so you can't see it. Try a

```
sudo bash -c 'printenv PATH; type -a rfkill'
```

This should display the PATH properly.

Comment: How command /usr/sbin/rfkill called when /usr/sbin is not in $PATH?

Comment: You have never answered the question.

Comment: If you use an absolute or relative path for a command, the `PATH` variable is ignored anyway.

Comment: See [here](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-path-environment-variable) how PATH works.

Comment: I am sure that no answer when command is not in the PATH then how to search it in the webpage you provided.

Comment: Read properly. It says _The reason we don’t need to specify paths for some commands is because of the $PATH variable_. In other words, if you don't use the PATH variable, you have to specify the path for the command. In my answer, I specified the path for the command explicitly, and therefore the PATH variable is not relevant (and actually ignored).

Comment: @user1934428 it looks like the OP was asking WHY IS `rfkill` getting called, not HOW CAN they call it. I just updated the question to change `how` to `why is` to clarify that.

Comment: @EdMorton: I understood first the question as *how* to invoke an executable, which is not in the PATH, but now I indeed realize that it asks about *why* it is called.